# How to save JSONObject containing <br /> tag in an Array using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, json

i am newbie in android.Can someone please help me how can i remove 
 from JSON and then store it in an Array then get values inside loop using java.Here is the JSON:
 i am writing this code:

```
String jsonArr[];
     private void getRequiredProducts(String parameter)
         {   Toast.makeText(context,"getRequiredProducts",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             try
             {

            responseJson = new JSONObject();
            responseJson = ServerRequest.sendRequest(url,parameter);
            Log.i(product_Tag,responseJson.toString());
             jsonArr = responseJson.toString().split("<br />");
            Log.i("ProductsArray:","values:" + jsonArr);
             }
             catch (JSONException e) {
                    errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
                    ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


    }
```

but every time i am getting Exception in console:

> 12-10 00:35:52.330: W/System.err(25377): org.json.JSONException: Value
>   53 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject 12-10
>   00:35:52.330: W/System.err(25377):    at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 12-10 00:35:52.330:
>   W/System.err(25377):  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:158) 12-10 00:35:52.330:
>   W/System.err(25377):  at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171) 12-10 00:35:52.330:
>   W/System.err(25377):  at
>   com.survey.management.activity.ServerRequest.sendRequest(ServerRequest.java:44)
>   **code added for ServerRequest.java**

```
public class ServerRequest {

    public static JSONObject sendRequest(String url, String parameter)
            throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, IOException,
            JSONException {
        JSONObject responseJson = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = SessionManager.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
      httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        if (!parameter.equals("null")) {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(parameter));

        }
        Log.i("URL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",url);
        Log.i("PARAMETERS>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", parameter);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StringBuilder responseStr = AndroidUtil.inputStreamToString(response
                .getEntity().getContent());
        Log.i("responseJson http:", "" + response);
        Log.i("responseString", "" + responseStr);
        responseJson = new JSONObject(responseStr.toString());
        Log.i("responseJson", "" + responseJson);
        return responseJson;
    }
}
```

this is the JSON I am getting from Service: and a log of this line **Log.i("responseJson", "" + responseJson);**

> 12-10 01:17:54.565: I/responseString(2563): 53,"ACCESS 08","Galaxy Ask
>   Proximity Keytag (Grey) YXO
>   0020",21,NULL,3.03,4.84,"ACCESS_08.JPG","Galaxy MAX
>   keytag.",NULL,"GALAXY
>   YX0-0020","PAN206",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",6.75,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"active"54,"BATTERY 06","3.6v Lithium 1/2 AA
>   Battery",21,NULL,2.5,4,"BATTERY_06.JPG","1/2 AA Battery",NULL,"EVE
>   ER14250","BAT034",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",7.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"active"55,"BATTERY 07","AA Battery",21,NULL,0.4,0.64,"BATTERY_07.JPG","AA
>   Battery",NULL,"PROCELL
>   MN1500","BAT019",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",2.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"active"59,"CONTROL 26","Scantronic 8400 eight channel
>   digi",21,NULL,31.79,54.4,"CONTROL_26.JPG","Scantronic 8400 eight
>   channel
>   digi",NULL,"8400UK-21","8400UK-21",0.1,0,0,0,1,0.1,"Y","7010","YES",65.45,NULL,"Scantronic
>   8400 eight channel digi",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 60,"FIRE 07","KAC
>   WR2072-SR Surface call point.",21,NULL,6,9.6,"FIRE_07.JPG","KAC
>   WR2072-SR Surface call point.",NULL,"KAC
>   (4003)","CAL002",0.033,0,0,0,0.5,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",48.55,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"active"63,"MISC 06","TKC HLR Handy Little Relay 12v
>   DC",21,NULL,7.4,11.85,"MISC_06.JPG","TKC HLR Handy Little Relay 12v
>   DC",NULL,"REL000","REL000",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",14.208,NULL,"TKC
>   HLR Handy Little Relay 12v DC",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 64,"MISC
>   07","TKC Very Handy Little (VHL) Relay 12v
>   DC",21,NULL,8.27,13.23,"MISC_07.JPG","TKC HLR Handy Little Relay 12v
>   DC",NULL,"REL002","REL002",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",15.8784,NULL,"TKC
>   Very Handy Little (VHL) Relay 12v DC",NULL,NULL,"active"67,"POWER 02","ACT 1313 12v Spike
>   Suppressor.",21,NULL,7.5,12,"POWER_02.JPG","ACT 1313 12v Spike
>   Suppressor.",NULL,"SPI001","SPI001",0.01,0,0,0,0.5,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",25,NULL,"ACT
>   1313 12v Spike Suppressor",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 68,"SIGNAL
>   07","Versus 3G STU (stand
>   alone)",21,NULL,135,216,"No_Image.PNG","Versus 3G STU (stand
>   alone)",NULL,"VERSUS 38232
>   3G","COM012",0.01,0,0,0,1,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",259.2,NULL,"Versus 3G
>   STU (stand alone)",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 69,"SIGNAL 10","Texecom
>   Premier Com 300",21,NULL,27.69,46.96,"SIGNAL_10.JPG","Texecom Premier
>   COM 300.",NULL,"TEXECOM
>   CEA-0001","COM013",0.01,0,0,0,1,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",56.5,NULL,"Texecom
>   Premier Com 300",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 70,"SMOKE 09","Apollo S65 24v
>   Optical Smoke Detector
>   D206.",21,NULL,17.65,28.24,"SMOKE_09.JPG","Apollo S65 24v Optical
>   Smoke Detector
>   D206.",NULL,"SMO007","SMO007",0.033,0,0,0,1,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",60,NULL,"Apollo
>   S65 24v Optical Smoke Detector D206",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 71,"SMOKE
>   11","Apollo XP95 base.",21,NULL,1.8,2.88,"SMOKE_11.JPG","Apollo XP95
>   base.",NULL,"SMO015","SMO015",0.01,0,0,0,1,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",4.37,NULL,"Apollo
>   XP95 base",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 72,"SMOKE 15","Can of Smoke
>   (Detector Tester)",21,NULL,7.5,12,"SMOKE_15.JPG","Can of Smoke
>   (Detector Tester).",NULL,"SOLO
>   83001","CAN001",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",14.44,NULL,"Can
>   of Smoke (Detector Tester)",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 80,"POWER
>   24","CR123A 3v Lithuim
>   Battery",21,NULL,1.85,3.92,"No_Image.PNG","CR123A 3v Lithuim
>   Battery",NULL,"VISONIC
>   0-9913-N","BAT042",0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",5.64,NULL,"CR123A
>   3v Lithium Battery",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 84,"INTLESS0027","Powermax
>   MCT-124 Wireless Double Button Portable
>   Transmitter.",18,NULL,25,51.64,"INTLESS0027.JPG","Wireless Double
>   Button Portable Transmitter with twin button operation to prevent
>   accidental distress
>   signalling.",NULL,"MCT-124","RAD198",0.01,0,0,0,0.25,0.01,"Y","7010","YES",62.14,NULL,"Powermax
>   MCT-124 Wireless Double Button Portable
>   Transmitter.",NULL,NULL,"active"
> 85,"CABLE0027","CAT5 Duct Grade
>   Cable 305m box",11,NULL,35.95,120,"Cable0027.JPG","CAT5 Duct Grade
>   Cable 305m box",NULL,"COMMTECH
>   B0193AXNCPE","CAB175",0.01,0,0,0,4,0.01,"Y","7010","NO",144.38,NULL,"CAT5
>   Duct Grade Cable 305m box",NULL,NULL,"active"86,"SECLIGHT0073","3 way 20amp 240volt Junction
>   Box",17,NULL,2,3.52,"SECLIGHT0073.JPG","3 way 20amp 240volt Junction
>   Box",NULL,"CLICK WA074","JBS014",0.0

Comment: What's the code for sendRequest() inside ServerRequest.java?

Comment: the response string is not valid JSON, it looks like a list of values.. JSON should be of the form { "key": value, "key2":value2 ... }

Comment: no i am getting this json and i already have done work with this json using javascript first i need to use split function to split <br/> and store values in an array

Comment: but over here the split function is not responding whats the reason  ?

Comment: @user1668447 Try out to parse the response by splitting it with `\n` as `jsonArr = responseJson.toString().split("\n");`

Comment: It's not working because the JSON parser is failing to parse the String as valid JSON: "JSONException: Value 53 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: Please post your actual Json response. In Json formate.

Comment: please see edit ihave added complete JSON

Comment: @GrIsHu  your suggested code not working same console error which  i posted above

Comment: your JSON is not valid.You should fix it first.

Comment: can someone please help me how can i deal with CSV i am getting csv FORM of data from service not json how can i handle in android ?

Answer (score 1):

I dnt need to use BufferReader i just return String from my ServerRequest Class instead of returning JSON.After that i call function and apply loop.

```
public class ServerRequest1 {

    public static String sendRequest(String url, String parameter)
            throws UnknownHostException, SocketException, IOException,
            JSONException {
        JSONObject responseJson = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = SessionManager.getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        if (!parameter.equals("null")) {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(parameter));

        }

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        StringBuilder responseStr = AndroidUtil.inputStreamToString(response
                .getEntity().getContent());
          return responseStr.toString();
    }
}
```

**in Another java class:**

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String...params) {

    getRequiredProducts(parameter);
    return null;

    }
     private void getRequiredProducts(String parameter)
     { 
         try
         {
             String getRequiredProducts_String  = ServerRequest1.sendRequest(url,parameter);
             String[] getRequiredProducts_Str_Array = getRequiredProducts_String.split("<br />");

             for(int i=0;i<getRequiredProducts_Str_Array.length;i++)
             {
                 Log.i("getRequiredProducts_Str_Array :",getRequiredProducts_Str_Array[i]);
             }
          }
         catch (JSONException e) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
                ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your CSV file data as below:

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             String[] RowData = line.split(",");
             date = RowData[0];
             value = RowData[1];
            // do something with "data" and "value"
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle exception
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
```

Comment: this is CSV not a JSON can you please help me how to handle CSV in android using Java.i dnt have any idea how to handle this ?

Comment: i am not reading it from a file i am tryig to hit service and getting CSV from Service.

Comment: may i need to only use this code after getting json response may i need to convert jsonObject into String or not ?

Comment: You just need to pass the response in Bufferreader only do not need to convert it into Json object. After getting all the response you can convert it into jsonobject.

Comment: This comments help me to understand the issue